# Prove: the difference of two outer measures is an outer measure

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose there are two outer measure functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu(\cdot)$, $v(\cdot)$ such that $\mu(\cdot) \geq v(\cdot)$. Prove that there exists another outer measure function $\lambda(\cdot)$ such that $\lambda+v=\mu$.

I am stuck at proving that this outer measure is monotonic. Any clues?

Comment: It would follow from this theorem that there don't exist two outer measures, $\mu,\nu$, on a bounded subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mu(x)\geq\nu(x)$ and $\mu(C)=\nu(C)<\infty$ except for when $\mu=\nu$ everywhere. If such measures were to exist, then we could extend them to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by assigning no weight to any set outside of $C$, producing a counter example to the theorem. This state of affairs seems intuitive to me, but perhaps that is helpful.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I provided a counterexample - the claim is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this question as my measure theory exercise. However, the claim is not true and there exists a counterexample:
Take $\mu$ as a counting measure and take $\nu$ as an indicator function taking value 1 if the set is not a null set.

Then it is straightforward that both functions are outer measures but $\mu-\nu$ does not satisfy countable subadditivity.